# Getting Array of objects with values but when trying to use them - they are undefined

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, undefined

I've got problem with this weird array with objects that are not null in debug, but when trying to use them in one way or another they are undefined...
To be more specified:

[image: array]

the code:

```
export interface ICollectPoint {
  name: string,
  shortName: string,
  street: string,
  buildingNumber: string,
  apartmentNumber: string,
  zipCode: string,
  city: string
}

collectPoints: ICollectPoint[] = [];

this.collectPoints = [...this.logisticMethod.collectPoints]; // [{...}, {...}, {...}] - array with some objects - ICollectPoint { name, shortname }
const a = this.collectPoints[0].name
```

`a = undefined`

Can someone help me with that ?

**EDIT**:

The code is in component with changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
and I'm using this on ngOnInit()

Comment: *Screenshots will say more maybe*, [no they won't](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Please create a [mcve]

Comment: You are calling `this.arrayFromPicture` before it's defined, thats why are you getting error. Message is pretty clear. Somehow this array is empty/undefined while you call it. If you need more help, we need more informations and code.

Comment: the collectPoints array is defined.

Comment: If you have some async data retrieval (collectPoints filled out from an http request, for instance), it could be that the values you see in the debug are actually filled in after you do a = collectPoints[0].name.

Comment: @ACEG thank you for your answer. The collectPoints is in memory and I've got all the values in it when a = collectPoints[0].name is called

Comment: OK, just something that has bitten me in the past :) What is the value of this.collectPoints[0] at the const a = ... line?

Comment: Your screenshot shows ‘Name’ but you try to access ‘name’..?

Comment: @ACEG It's an object with properties filled with values (ICollectionPoint ) like { name: 'some string'; shortName: 'some string' }

Comment: Thanks for your answer @MikeOne. It's not case sensitive I think, I use interface props

Comment: Definitely case sensitive :-)

Comment: @MikeOne I'm getting: Property 'Name' does not exist on type 'ICollectPoint'. Did you mean 'name'?ts(2551)
ICollectPoint.interface.ts(2, 3): 'name' is declared here.

Answer (score 1):

Big thanks to @MikeOne - he get me to the right path to solve this issue.
And the issue was on WebApi side - [JsonProperty] on CollectPointDTO had all of props with Big letters like "Name", "ShortName" and that couse issues for maping in angular on interface props...

Weird was that in debug I can see those values mapped ...
Maybe this answer will help someone with simillar problems.